# How to monitor enter and exit from Multiple Polylines using geofencing

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geofencing, google-polyline

I am building flutter app and wants to achieve enter and exit of user location from multiple polyline.
I wanted the fast way to know to which polyline user entered or exit from multiple polylines.

I know the way by iterating each polyline with isLocationOnPath() and check with current location but it takes too much time when have large number of polyline and check each one by one.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: are those polylines overlapping?  also how big is that "large number"? 100s, 1000s, more?

Comment: No, those polylines are not overlapping. and yeah those polylines are n numbers of.

Comment: then compute "bouncing box" of each polyline so you can fast eliminate most of non matching polylines, what is `n`? 100s, 1000s, more?

Comment: ok, n means X number of polylines. it can be 100s, 1000s or even more than that.

Comment: of course i meant "bounding box", not "bouncing box"